# NIC enabled promiscuous mode, unicast packets aren't sniffed out

Tags: network-programming, driver, ethernet, vxworks

I have my NIC in promiscuous mode, set within my driver. I'm running a hardwired connection between three machines on the same subnet (sending unicast UDP messages).

```
  endM2Init (&pDrvCtrl->geiEndObj, M2_ifType_ethernet_csmacd,
        pDrvCtrl->geiAddr, ETHER_ADDR_LEN, pDrvCtrl->geiMaxMtu, 100000000,
        IFF_NOTRAILERS | IFF_SIMPLEX | IFF_MULTICAST | IFF_BROADCAST | IFF_PROMISC);
```

When I verify the destination address within the packet header, the only packets that are actually being sniffed out are typically broadcast messages (the source address is correct, but I can't sniff out unicast packets).

If I direct a packet to the machine doing the sniffing, I can still see the unicast packet without any issues.

At first I assumed this was because my local switch was managing the packets. I used the web-interface for my specific switch and enabled port mirroring (Ex: Source port 1, Destination port 7). This, however, yielded the same results. From my understanding, port mirroring on the switch sends everything destined to port 1 also to port 7.

I then tried a direct connection from machine A to machine B, while still sending the unicast packets to, the now disconnected, machine C to see if machine B would see any changes in packet sniffing. This once again, yielded the same results.

If machine A and machine B are directly connected, does it make sense to expect machine B to sniff out packets that are destined to an address not even in the loop? I appreciate any and all comments/answers regarding this topic.

Comment: I switched from using NIC 1 (gei1) to NIC 0 (gei0) and I was able to sniff packets destined for a third party host machine. Which still leaves the question as to why NIC 0 is able to establish a promiscuous connection but NIC 1 stops receiving after the first successful capture.